# Can't use Abstract Class (ABCMeta) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, flask-restful

I'm creating a Flask-RESTful application with SQLAlchemy.

I'm struggling to use the Abstract Class concept in Python 3. According to the python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) the usage should be as simple as:

```
### Python documentation ###
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...
    def __len__(self):
        ...
    def get_iterator(self):
        return iter(self)

class MyIterable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None

    def get_iterator(self):
        return self.__iter__()

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is MyIterable:
            if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented

MyIterable.register(Foo)
```

But, in my implementation within a package, I'm receiving the following error:

**file: apis.base_api.py**

```
class BaseAPI(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def entity(self):
        pass

    def checkId(self, unique_id):
        try:
            if not unique_id:
                abort(405)
            obj = self.entity.get_valid(int(unique_id))            
            if not obj:
                raise Exception('%s nao encontrado' % (self.__class__.__name__))
            return obj
        except:
            abort(404)
        ...
```

**file: apis.projects.py**

```
class ProjectAPI(Resource):

    @property
    def entity(self):
        return Projeto #this is my model class object

    def get(self, unique_id=unique_id):
        obj self.checkId(unique_id)
        return {self.entity.__api_name__: obj.serialize()}
        #the return (tested before) is like {"projects": project.data})
    ...
```

**file: apis.__init__.py**

```
from apis.base_api import BaseAPI
from apis.projects import ProjectAPI

BaseAPI.register(ProjectAPI)
```

I get no "compilation" error, and the applications starts running. When I try to reach the ProjectAPI I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'ProjectAPI' object has no attribute 'checkId'

Shouldn't the BaseAPI.checkid method be abstractedly inherited to the ProjectAPI since I registered it? What am I doing wrong??

Tnx in advance

---

### Identified an error

When creating the ProjectAPI class from my BaseAPI class (in other words, my Concrete class from my Abstract class), I should use the Python 3 syntax, extending the Abstract class:

```
class ProjectAPI(BaseAPI, Resource):
...
```

And should **NOT register** the ProjectAPI on BaseAPI.

Though, even fixing this, the error below shows up:

> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Comment: Two things: please fix the indentation in your question, and make sure you aren't confusing `checkid` with `checkId`, as Python is case-sensitive.

Comment: @chepner I'm fixing the indentation, thought it only happened when copying the code here. I mispelled the function just here as well. Tnx

Comment: I found that the Resource extending is originating the problem, as deleting it makes the concrete instantiating works.

Comment: It appears that `Resource` is already using a metaclass. The fix should be to create a new metaclass that extends both `ABCMeta` and whatever `Resource` uses, and use *that* as the metaclass for `ProjectAPI`.